# How do cloud and image indices correspond in tod_training?

Tags: ros, object-recognition, tod-training

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, my task is to retrieve 3d points that correspond to 2d points (guess inliers) from a query cloud. There is [tod::PCLToPoints](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/object_recognition/tod_training/include/tod/training/clouds.h) which exactly does that. I am wondering though why there is one common scaling factor for both x and y indices from image coordinate space.

```
int u = float(cloud.width) / image.cols * x
int v = float(cloud.width) / image.cols * y
// such that cloud.at(u, v) corresponds to image(x, y)
```

What's the reason behind this? I expected that the proportion between y and v is given by dividing cloud height by number of rows in the image, yet experiments show that the approach tod::PCLToPoints is correct (on point clouds and images gathered with tod_training scripts and Kinect camera).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9817/how-do-cloud-and-image-indices-correspond-in-tod_training?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The depth is always 640x480. But the image itself can have a different size/aspect ratio with the Kinect. Hence, you need to rely on the cloud.width to get the right dimensions/ratio.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1